# error in Android Manifest file, Call Recorder

Tags: android, manifest, mediarecorder

I am trying to record voice calls when someone calls. I have copied the code from multiple sources. But there is error in Manifest file. All problems in debug/AndroidManifest_xml. AAPT_ error_ 'device_description' is incompatible with attribute description (attr) reference.
android:description="device_description" and  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN". have the problem.

CODE:
MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        Context mContext;
    
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
        private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
        private ComponentName mAdminName;
        static final int REQUEST = 112;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mContext = this;
    
            try {
                // Initiate DevicePolicyManager.
                mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminDemo.class);
    
                if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Click on Activate button to secure your application.");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    // mDPM.lockNow();
                    // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    // TrackDeviceService.class);
                    // startService(intent);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //do here
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was  allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

DeviceAdminDemo.java:      
      
    public class DeviceAdminDemo extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    
        public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        };
    
        public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        };
    }
      
TService.java:      

    public class TService extends Service {
        private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
        private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
        private CallBr br_call;
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.d("service", "destroy");
    
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    
            final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
            filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
            this.br_call = new CallBr();
            this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
    
        }
      
CallBr.java:      

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
        private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;
    
        MediaRecorder recorder = null;
        private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
        private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
        private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
        private int currentFormat = 0;
        private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4,
                MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };
        private String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4,
                AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP };
        String RECORD_DIRECTORY = "Call Records";
        static final int REQUEST = 112;
        private boolean isRecordStarted = false;
    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        if (wasRinging == true) {
    
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                                String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                                if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    
                                    startMediaRecorder();
    
                                } else {
                                    //do here
    
                                    startMediaRecorder();
    
                                }
                            } else {
                                //do here
    
                                startMediaRecorder();
    
                            }
    
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (isRecordStarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            isRecordStarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private boolean startMediaRecorder(){
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            try{
                recorder.reset();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
                recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    
                MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                    public void onError(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                        //Log.e(TAG, "OnErrorListener " + arg1 + "," + arg2);
                        terminateAndEraseFile();
                    }
                };
                recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    
                MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                        //Log.e(TAG, "OnInfoListener " + arg1 + "," + arg2);
                        terminateAndEraseFile();
                    }
                };
                recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    
    
                recorder.prepare();
                // Sometimes prepare takes some time to complete
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                recorder.start();
                //recordstarted = true;
                isRecordStarted = true;
                return true;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.getMessage();
                terminateAndEraseFile();
                return false;
            }
        }
        private String getFilename() {
            File MediaDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), RECORD_DIRECTORY );
            // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    
            if (!MediaDirectory.exists()) {
                Log.d("dirrrrrr", "" + MediaDirectory.mkdirs());
                MediaDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
            return (MediaDirectory + "/" + out + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
        }
        private void terminateAndEraseFile(){
            try{
                if (null != recorder) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
    
                    recorder = null;
                }
            }catch(RuntimeException stopException){
    
            }
        }
        private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
                for (String permission : permissions) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
      
Layout_my_admin.xml:      

   

 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
            <device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
                <uses-policies>
                    <force-lock />
                </uses-policies>
          
   

 main_AndroidManifest.xml: 

     
   

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.callrecorder">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CallRecorder">
    
            <receiver
                android:name="com.example.callrecorder.DeviceAdminDemo"
                android:description="device_description"
                android:label="device_admin_label"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                    android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />
    
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    
            <service android:name=".TService" >
            </service>
    
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
        </device-admin>
    
    </LinearLayout>
           

debug/AndroidManifest.xml:  

        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.callrecorder"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
    
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="16"
            android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
            android:debuggable="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:testOnly="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.CallRecorder" >
            <receiver
                android:name="com.example.callrecorder.DeviceAdminDemo"
                android:description="device_description"
                android:label="device_admin_label"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                    android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    
            <service android:name="com.example.callrecorder.TService" >
            </service>
    
            <activity android:name="com.example.callrecorder.MainActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```